# record created longer than +90 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a DB which collects Work Hours Reports from workers, 
and i've been asked to create an alert for a specific division 
of active contracts which the last report date was bigger than 90 days

I have the ReportDate column which contains the entries and I am not sure how to create it distinct, without using the GETDATE function

as mentioned, I tried the getdate function which obviously is not valid in this case

(not code but the query needed) 
select distinct (newcontractid) 
where last ReportDate is bigger than 90 days...

Comment: (1) Please provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Why are you mentioning `GETDATE()`?  It is not a MySQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select contractid
from t
where t.status = 'active'  -- whatever this is
group by contractid
having max(reportdate) < current_date - interval '90 day';
```

This uses standard SQL syntax.  In MySQL, the date functions would be:

```
having max(reportdate) < current_date - interval 90 day;
```

In SQL Server:

```
having max(reportdate) < dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to be the way, 
However, can I get behind trying to add the third column (reportdate) to the group by without it changing my results?


select distinct h.NewContractID, c.new_contactidName, h.ReportDate
from HourReport h
inner join HrProd_MSCRM.[dbo].[new_contract] c on h.NewContractID = c.new_contract_num
where h.DivisionID = 114
and c.new_status = 3 
and c.statecode = 0
group by h.NewContractID, c.new_contactidname, h.ReportDate
having max(reportdate) < dateadd(day, -90, getdate())

Comment: @Coheneil . . . I am guessing you want `max(reportdate)` as reportdate` in the `select`.